# WordPress Contact form7 submit button and email validation issue

Tags: wordpress, contact-form-7, email-validation, hubspot-crm

In WordPress contact form 7, we have used email validation filters. It is working like when I entered any Gmail account id and clicks submit it's showing error messages 'Please enter company email'.but the problem is though it is showing the error message data is getting captured at hubspot CRM.

We connected our WordPress contact form7 to hubspot by bit integration

Is there any custom js we need to include ?